# How to format like number format in jquery on the simple way?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to replace content on hrg1+id from ajax in php like this:

```
<p id="hrg1<?php echo $id; ?>">Rp.<?php echo number_format($price,0,",",".") ?></p>
```

But the value pass from ajax like this:

```
$("#hrg1"+id).html("Rp."+price);
```

How to format like number format in jquery on the simple way?

```
Rp.<?php echo number_format($price,0,",",".") ?>
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: http://numeraljs.com

Answer (score 0):

Here my ref on my note:

```
function akoma(nStr){
nStr += '';
x = nStr.split(',');
x1 = x[0];
x2 = x.length > 1 ? ',' + x[1] : '';
var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
}
return x1 + x2;
}

alert(akoma(price));
$("#price"+id).html(akoma(price(0)));
```